# VBA PasteSpecial Transpose gives Application-defined or object-defined error (1004)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a whole column (minus the heading) from a CSV file and paste it transposed into my excel file.

"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error (1004)" flags up on the last line where I'm trying to run the paste-transpose operation and I can't figure out why?

Code is as follows:

```
Sub UpdateData()

Dim LastRow_1 As Long      ' Set up variable                                                                           
LastRow_1 = Workbooks("ProconData").Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row ' Find last non-blank row


Dim CopyRange_1 As Range      ' Set up variable  
Set CopyRange_1 = Workbooks("ProconData").Worksheets("ProconData").Range("A2").Resize(LastRow_1, 1)  ' Define copy range

Dim PasteRange_1 As Range      ' Set up variable  
Set PasteRange_1 = Workbooks("TBM Ground Condition 
Record").Worksheets("RECORD").Range("LV4") '.Resize(4, 334 + LastRow_1) ' Define paste range

Workbooks("TBM Ground Condition Record").Worksheets("RECORD").Range(PasteRange_1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues  ' Transpose & paste data

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Since you declare `PasteRange_1` as a range, that has the references, don't use them again. Just do `PasteRange_1.PasteSpecial` ...but where do you copy the data?

Comment: You have not copied your range to paste. Since you set your copy and paste ranges as variables. You need to `CopyRange_1.Copy Destination:= PasteRange_1` add your Transpose etc.

Comment: @BruceWayne Doesn't setting it up as done in the 5th row do just that? Apologies if I'm wrong, I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: @GMalc That line of code doesn''t allow me to add things like the Transpose modifier without compiling errors, any suggestions?

Comment: @AshwinArutchelvam how exactly are you writing the copy/paste lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just substitute:

```
Workbooks("TBM Ground Condition Record").Worksheets("RECORD").Range(PasteRange_1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues  ' Transpose & paste data
```

with:

```
CopyRange_1.Copy ' copy the range to be copied
PasteRange_1.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues  ' Transpose & paste data ' paste the copied range to the one set for pasting
```

since:

1. you weren't copying anything
2. you already set `PasteRange_1` as a `Range` object so you can directly use it as a `Range` reference. While a `Range` object can't be the argument of the `Range()` property of the `Range` object itself... (you may have a look at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel))

BTW, your code assumes that "ProconData" workbook first worksheet is named "ProconData", which may not be always true

you'd better reference the wanted sheet by its name and so change:

```
LastRow_1 = Workbooks("ProconData").Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '
```

to:

```
LastRow_1 = Workbooks("ProconData").Worksheets("ProconData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '
```

Comment: @AshwinArutchelvam, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below

```
Sub UpdateData()
    Dim LastRow_1 As Long      ' Set up variable
    LastRow_1 = Workbooks("ProconData").Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Find last non-blank row
    Dim CopyRange_1 As Range      ' Set up variable
    Set CopyRange_1 = Workbooks("ProconData").Worksheets("ProconData").Range("A2").Resize(LastRow_1, 1)  ' Define copy range
    CopyRange_1.Copy
    Workbooks("TBM Ground Condition Record").Worksheets("RECORD").Range("LV4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True  '.Resize(4, 334 + LastRow_1) ' Define paste range
End Sub
```